# IBM Worklight 6 - "FWLAC0401W: No user appears to be logged, check the Application Center security configuration"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I have installed the IBM Worklight Application Center using IBM Installation Manager in a WAS  Liberty profile application server.

When trying to access: `http://host:10080/appcenterconsole/applications/Applications.html`

The following error message is being returned:

> FWLAC0401W: No user appears to be logged, check the Application Center
>   security configuration.

What is causing it?

Comment: Did you follow this documentation? App Center Preliminary Information: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/r_preliminary_information.html  and Configuring the Application Center after installation: 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/c_configuration_of_the_applicati.html

Comment: yes i read the topic about liberty profile and all the parameters are present in server.xml. The exception is `javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONException: com.ibm.puremeap.resources.exceptions.AccessControlException: FWLAC0401W: No user appears to be logged, check the Application Center security configuration.` what doest it means by `check the Application Center security configuration.` thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that no user principal was found in the security context. Something with the security settings is wrong.

On WebSphere Application Server, the typical problem is that application security is not enabled.

If you have WebSphere Liberty profile, then check server.xml. It must contain:

```
<feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
```

It must also contain something like the following (details vary depending on LDAP or not):

```
<application id="appcenterconsole" ...>
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
            ...
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</application>
<application id="applicationcenter" ...>
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
            ...
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
    ...
</application>
```

If you have WebSphere full profile, then open the WAS admin console.

Go to Security > Global Security > Application Security

Ensure that "Enable application security" is checked.

I think "Enable application security" works only if "Enable administrative security" is checked as well, hence make sure both are checked.

If you change it then:

- hit apply button
- save to master configuration
- restart the web server (it does not work without restart)

Now: exit the WAS admin console or start a new browser (as you cannot log into application center with the same browser that has the admin console open). Go to application center console and log in. The effect should disappear.

Note: the IBM install manager changes the "Enable application security" correctly only if "Enable administrative security" is enabled. But the IBM install manager does not restart WAS. The user must restart WAS when the IBM install manager changed those flags.

Comment: thanks appSecurity-1.0 was missing. don't know why. the documentation is reporting it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the user you use is not a user recognized by the security registry of Liberty Profile.

So surely something is wrong with your server.xml. Could you give its content and the user you use to connect ? And also the AppCenter version.

Thanks.

Comment: Version: 20130614-0631<br/>connecting to host:10080/appcenterconsole/applications/Applications.html doesn't ask me for a user/password login.

Comment: So it surely means that it is missing somethig in the server.xml file like the basisRegistry section or the security roles for the applications.

Comment: sorry i can't post the server.xml too many lines. basicregistry is there:  <basicRegistry id="applicationcenter-registry" realm="ApplicationCenter">
        <user name="appcenteradmin" password="demo"/>
        <user name="demo" password="demo"/>

        <group name="appcentergroup">
            <member name="appcenteradmin"/>
            <member name="demo"/>
        </group>
    </basicRegistry>